# Array of objects count and update numbering only if the boolean of top row is true

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm struggling to get the following to work.

I have a sorted array of objects which contains **No**,**Title**, and **Top** (Which means the top row):

```
var arr = [];
arr = [
    {No: "", Title: "John", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "John", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "John", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "Kyle", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "Jonnah", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "Jonnah", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: false},
]
```

I want to count and update the numbering **No** only if the **Top** is true.

So, below is the results that I expected to get:

```
arr = [
    {No: "1", Title: "John", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "John", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "John", Top: false},
    {No: "2", Title: "Kyle", Top: true},
    {No: "3", Title: "Jonnah", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "Jonnah", Top: false},
    {No: "4", Title: "Hyuri", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: false},
]
```

Following is an attempt I've made:

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(i!=(arr.length-1)){
        if(arr[i].Top){
            arr[i].No = i+1;
        }else{
            arr[i+1].No = arr[i].No;
        }
    }
    
}
```

The results that i get:

```
[
    {"No": 1, "Title": "John", "Top": true},
    {"No": "", "Title": "John", "Top": false},
    {"No": "", "Title": "John", "Top": false},
    {"No": 4, "Title": "Kyle", "Top": true},
    {"No": 5, "Title": "Jonnah", "Top": true},
    {"No": "", "Title": "Jonnah", "Top": false},
    {"No": 7, "Title": "Hyuri", "Top": true},
    {"No": "", "Title": "Hyuri", "Top": false},
    {"No": "", "Title": "Hyuri", "Top": false}
]
```

How can i get the results that i want?

Comment: Your code looks at `arr[i]` and `arr[i + 1]` at the same time, but according to your description, each row should be looked at alone.

Comment: By having a second variable (and don't use `var`, use `let` for mutable and `const` for immutabl) that you only increment when Top is true. But, are you trying to modify your data in place, or are you trying to create a derivative array with new data? Because that changes the answer, too.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a closure over `count` and update the object, if necessary.

```js
const
    data = [{ No: "", Title: "John", Top: true }, { No: "", Title: "John", Top: false }, { No: "", Title: "John", Top: false }, { No: "", Title: "Kyle", Top: true }, { No: "", Title: "Jonnah", Top: true }, { No: "", Title: "Jonnah", Top: false }, { No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: true }, { No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: false }, { No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: false }],
    result = data.map((count => o => ({
        ...o,
        ...o.Top && { No: (++count).toString() }
    }))(0));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Since we're updating the actual elements themselves, we don't even need to create a new array, though: might as well `forEach` this (or stick with the for loop if we need to run fast of course)

Answer (score 1):

Nina's answer is perfect and you should use it but as the code they wrote seems a bit obscure for someone new to javascript I'm writing an answer to clarify the mistake on the question's code:

While iterating over the array, you could use the pattern `for row of arr` but I'm going to stick with your "classic" for as the original question uses:

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    // Don't you want to process the last row?
    // Change the for "range", from i<arr.length to i<arr.lenght-1
    if(i!=(arr.length-1)){  
        if(arr[i].Top){
            arr[i].No = arr[i].No++
        }
        // You need to bump the `No` property, not the i (index) 
        // You don't need the else
    }
    
}
```

If you want a global count, you can do it like this:

```
for(var i=0, j=1;i<arr.length;i++){
     if(arr[i].Top){
         arr[i].No = j++ //using an external global counter here
     }
}
```

Comment: And remove the `if(i!=(arr.length-1))`, because the last row must also be processed.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as elegant as [Nina's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75699310/2422776), but keeping with the style you started with, you could hold an additional counter to keep track of the numbering you want:

```js
let counter = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i].Top) {
        ++counter;
        arr[i].No = counter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just put that counter inside the loop so it expires along with `i` at the end of it? =)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second variable that you only increment when Top is true:

```js
const arr = [
    {No: "", Title: "John", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "John", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "John", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "Kyle", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "Jonnah", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "Jonnah", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: false},
]

for(let i=0, j=1, e=arr.length; i<e; i++) {
  if(arr[i].Top) arr[i].No = j++;
}

console.log(arr)
```

And use `let` or `const`, never use `var`: `let` and `const` obey block scoping rules, `var` *very much* does not.

If you use the legacy `var` keyword you're declaring a variable scoped to the current execution context, i.e. "the entire function" if you declare it inside a function, *global scope* if you declare it outside a function because of [the magic of hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). Right now, your `i` is a global variable, even though you *only* wanted to use it for the duration of a loop.

**Don't use `var`.**

And ideally, don't use capitalised names for your properties, either. JS convention is to use UpperCamelCase only for classes, with properties, methods, and variables all using lowerCamelCase.

Answer (score 0):

Several answers already, but I wanted to give you one that's a little less condensed and easy to follow.

```js
const arr = [
    {No: "", Title: "John", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "John", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "John", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "Kyle", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "Jonnah", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "Jonnah", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: true},
    {No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: false},
    {No: "", Title: "Hyuri", Top: false},
]

let counter = 0

arr.forEach(row => {
  if (row.Top) {
    counter++
    row.No = String(counter)
  }
})
```

Comment: Better to scope that counter to the loop so it's gone by the time the work's done.

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses reduce to examine each object in the array. It has an accumulator `a`, which starts at the value 0 and is incremented when necessary.

Reduce calls an arrow function, passing in the accumulator and the current array item. It expects the result of the arrow function to be the new value of the accumulator after examining the current array item.

The ternary operator `?` is used to check if `c.Top` is true, and if so sets `c.No` to the incremented accumulator and makes that incremented value the new value of the accumulator. Otherwise, it returns the same accumulator value as before.

```js
const arr = [{"No":"","Title":"John","Top":true},{"No":"","Title":"John","Top":false},{"No":"","Title":"John","Top":false},{"No":"","Title":"Kyle","Top":true},{"No":"","Title":"Jonnah","Top":true},{"No":"","Title":"Jonnah","Top":false},{"No":"","Title":"Hyuri","Top":true},{"No":"","Title":"Hyuri","Top":false},{"No":"","Title":"Hyuri","Top":false}]

arr.reduce((a,c) => c.Top ? c.No = a+1 : a, 0)

console.log(arr)
```